# Convert Python dictionary to Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Python dictionary :

```
dic = {
       (u'aaa',u'bbb',u'ccc'):((0.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5), 1.4, 1),
       (u'kkk',u'ggg',u'ccc',u'sss'):((0.6, 1.2, 1.7, 1.5), 1.4, 2)
       }
```

I'd like to convert this dictionary to Spark DataFrame with columns :

`['key', 'val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5', 'val_6']`

example row (1) :

`key                  | val_1   |val_2 | val_3 | val_4  | val_5| val_6|`

`u'aaa',u'bbb',u'ccc' | 0.3     |1.2   |1.3    |1.5     |1.4   |1     |`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extract items, cast key to `list` and combine everything into a single `tuple`:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (list(k), ) + 
    v[0] + 
    v[1:] 
    for k, v in  dic.items()
]).toDF(['key', 'val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5', 'val_6'])

df.show()

## +--------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
## |                 key|val_1|val_2|val_3|val_4|val_5|val_6|
## +--------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
## |     [aaa, bbb, ccc]|  0.3|  1.2|  1.3|  1.5|  1.4|    1|
## |[kkk, ggg, ccc, sss]|  0.6|  1.2|  1.7|  1.5|  1.4|    2|
## +--------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: It works . Thanks . Short question about syntax , why need comma and parenthesis  in expression  `(list(k), )`

Comment: We want to concatenate three tuples. `(x, )` marks a single element tuple.